# Download File - VB6

Tags: vb6, download

Does anyone know how to download a file (without opening a webpage), and save it to a directory in Visual Basic 6.0?

Comment: **And 81 Qs with only 4 votes ???**

Comment: You don't need to include signature in your post - your user card is added automatically. Read [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#signatures) for more details.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to do it with code only (no Internet Transfer Control), [VBNet.mvps.org](http://vbnet.mvps.org/index.html?code/internet/urldownloadtofile.htm) has a really good how-to article that uses the URLDownloadToFile API call.

From the article:

> The URLDownloadToFile API is available
>   on all versions of the Windows
>   operating system (except Win3,
>   WinNT3.x). By passing the remote file
>   name and the local file path and name,
>   the API downloads the bits of the
>   specified file saving them as the
>   target name. The function works with
>   all file types - plain text, images,
>   html, mpg, wav and zip files etc.
>   without modification to the routine or
>   concern for the file being downloaded,
>   nor is there any apparent size
>   restriction or limitation.

```
Private Declare Function URLDownloadToFile Lib "urlmon" _
   Alias "URLDownloadToFileA" _
  (ByVal pCaller As Long, _
   ByVal szURL As String, _
   ByVal szFileName As String, _
   ByVal dwReserved As Long, _
   ByVal lpfnCB As Long) As Long

Private Const ERROR_SUCCESS As Long = 0
Private Const BINDF_GETNEWESTVERSION As Long = &H10
Private Const INTERNET_FLAG_RELOAD As Long = &H80000000

Public Function DownloadFile(sSourceUrl As String, _
                             sLocalFile As String) As Boolean

  //'Download the file. BINDF_GETNEWESTVERSION forces 
  //'the API to download from the specified source. 
  //'Passing 0& as dwReserved causes the locally-cached 
  //'copy to be downloaded, if available. If the API 
  //'returns ERROR_SUCCESS (0), DownloadFile returns True.
   DownloadFile = URLDownloadToFile(0&, _
                                    sSourceUrl, _
                                    sLocalFile, _
                                    BINDF_GETNEWESTVERSION, _
                                    0&) = ERROR_SUCCESS

End Function
```

FYI - in testing on Windows 7, it would only return the cached version, so I had to use the extra function mentioned in the article to clear it first (and that worked).

```
Private Declare Function DeleteUrlCacheEntry Lib "Wininet.dll" _
   Alias "DeleteUrlCacheEntryA" _
  (ByVal lpszUrlName As String) As Long
```

Then just call the above function with the destination URL first, to clear the cache.

Comment: You **don't need API calls**, you **don't need the Internet Transfer control**. Just do it the easy way, using native VB6 code. http://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2008/03/27/simple-asynchronous-downloads.aspx

Comment: +1, thank you very much for introducing me to these API calls.

Answer (score 6):

You don't need API calls, you don't need the Internet Transfer control. Just do it the easy way, using native VB6 code. Here's an excellent [article by Karl Peterson](http://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2008/03/27/simple-asynchronous-downloads.aspx) with sample code.

Comment: There was something I had never seen before. I have a full class using the WININET library so if I need to do this in VB again I will probably stick with that, but it is always good to have alternatives.

Comment: If Internet explorer's offline property is true this won't work. You'll get a file not found error.

Answer (score 4):

Try this

```
Sub DownloadFile(url, path)

   Dim objReq
   Dim objStream

   Set objReq = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
   objReq.Open "GET", url, False
   objReq.send

   If objReq.Status = 200 Then
       Set objStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
       objStream.Open
       objStream.Type = 1

       objStream.Write objReq.ResponseBody
       objStream.Position = 0

       objStream.SaveToFile path, 2
       objStream.Close
       Set objStream = Nothing
   End If

   Set objReq = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: I dont know why on this answer is no points. It's the only answer which realy works without inet control. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using the [Internet Transfer Control](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/163653)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the Internet Transfer control, see http://www.vb-helper.com/howto_get_file_from_web.html for a sample. If you need to specify credentials, check out http://support.microsoft.com/kb/173264 as well.

Answer (score 0):

I don't like the Internet Transfer Control because it is synchronous. Once you start a download your application is unresponsive until the file is downloaded or an error is thrown. There are plenty of good examples of using the **WININET** DLL to write asynchronous methods. It is not trivial, but it is also very do-able. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/537580/how-to-download-multiple-files-in-vb6-with-progress-bar) is an example from stackoverflow.

Comment: It **is** trivial to do asynchronous downloads in VB6 and it doesn't require API calls. See my answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1976152/download-file-vb6/1979417#1979417

Answer (score -2):

Try This:

```
My.Computer.Network.DownloadFile (*File to download*, *What to save it as*)
```

You must give it a filename in the *what to save it as*:

Example:

```
 My.Computer.Network.DownloadFile _
("http://www.cohowinery.com/downloads/WineList.txt", _
"C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Documents\WineList.txt")
```

Comment: This looks like VB.NET, question is about VB6