# Saving a file from an URL with WebBrowser with VB6

Tags: vb6, webbrowser-control

I have a project with VB6.

I need download a file from an URL. Then I use WebBrowser:

```
WebBrowser.Navigate "www.miurl.com/mifoto.jpg"
```

I need save mifoto.jpg directly to my path, I don't need any question about where I save it.

But WebBrowser always asks me to save it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Download File - VB6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1976152/download-file-vb6)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check this link it may be what you're looking for... I'd expect something like this may be best to do through the Windows API:

http://vbnet.mvps.org/index.html?code/internet/urldownloadtofile.htm

if you want to use the WebBrowser control I think there are a few properties that may help: Silent and Theater

Comment: Thanks Daniel. With UrlDownloadToFile run fine.