# VB6 - Inet can not download several files

Tags: url, vb6, download, inet

I'm using `Inet` in `Visual Basic 6` to download files.

There is no problem when downloading files that have url like:
"`http://HOST.com/PATH/FileName.txt`"
but Inet can not download files which have some Variables in url like:
"`http://HOST.com/PATH/download.php?FileCode=126`" .

Is there any way to solve this problem? If not, any other methods that can solve this?

Comment: Try technique in my answer to question about [asynchronous download in VB6](http://stackoverflow.com/a/538382/15639)

Comment: @MarkJ : That works fine, Now, How can i get the **REALL** File name with extension before downloading?

Comment: Sounds like you need the "Content Disposition" HTTP header. Not sure how to get that.

Comment: @MarkJ: Excellent. However I cannot get the name of file but I'm getting extension of file using Inet.getheader then I can use your method to download it.

Answer (score -1):

You can use of other downloading API in vb6 like Asyncron or call win32 app downloader maked by other softwares or programming language for example  Nsis or innosetup of setupfactory 9.

Comment: why down vote? u can for example use off this codes -> http://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2008/03/27/simple-asynchronous-downloads.aspx

Comment: I didn't vote down, but i asked question about INET. I know other methods.